# Geometrical optics problem and broader questions about the correct use of $\approx$ in physical calculations

Tags: optics, notation, geometric-optics, geometry, approximations

My textbook, *Fundamentals of Photonics, Third Edition*, by Saleh and Teich, gives the following:

[image]

This seems to be mathematically incorrect to me?

Firstly, the author stated that $\phi = \psi - \theta_1 \approx \dfrac{y}{-R} - \theta_1$, and then substitutes this into $\theta_2 = 2\phi + \theta_1$ to get $\theta_2 = 2\phi + \theta_1 = 2\left[ \dfrac{y}{-R} - \theta_1 \right] + \theta_1$. But shouldn't this be $\theta_2 = 2\phi + \theta_1 \approx 2\left[ \dfrac{y}{-R} - \theta_1 \right] + \theta_1$?

And lastly, the author stated that $y \approx y_1 + \theta_1 z_1$, and then substitutes this into $\dfrac{2y}{-R} - \theta_1$ to get $\dfrac{2y}{-R} - \theta_1 = \dfrac{2(y_1 + \theta_1 z_1)}{-R} - \theta_1$. But shouldn't this be $\dfrac{2y}{-R} - \theta_1 \approx \dfrac{2(y_1 + \theta_1 z_1)}{-R} - \theta_1$?

Taking all of this into account, the result would be

$$\theta_2 = 2\phi + \theta_1 \approx 2\left[ \dfrac{y}{-R} - \theta_1 \right] + \theta_1 = \dfrac{2y}{-R} - \theta_1 \approx \dfrac{2(y_1 + \theta_1 z_1)}{-R} - \theta_1,$$

which, if my understanding is correct, is a *very* different mathematical result, in terms of the mathematical conclusions we can draw from this, than what the author has, due to the differences between $=$ and $\approx$ and how we treat them in mathematical calculations.

I'm not familiar with how physicists go about their calculations, but, if my understanding of the mathematics is correct, $\approx$ is not necessarily transitive, so if we have that $A \approx B$ and $B \approx C$, it is not necessarily true that we therefore have $A \approx C$?

The author illustrates what I mean here in their next conclusion, which is a consequence of the, what I believe to be, erroneous mathematics of the last result:

[image]

If my understanding of the mathematics is correct, then due to the differences between $=$ and $\approx$, we cannot simply treat $\approx$ as $=$ and draw conclusions in a "chain" of equations and approximations such as $\theta_2 = 2\phi + \theta_1 \approx 2\left[ \dfrac{y}{-R} - \theta_1 \right] + \theta_1 = \dfrac{2y}{-R} - \theta_1 \approx \dfrac{2(y_1 + \theta_1 z_1)}{-R} - \theta_1$. Here, we have a case of $A = \theta_2 \approx B = 2\left[ \dfrac{y}{-R} - \theta_1 \right] + \theta_1$ and $B \approx C = \dfrac{2(y_1 + \theta_1 z_1)}{-R} - \theta_1$, and the author assumes that $\approx$ is transitive so that, logically, we have $(A \approx B) \land (B \approx C) \Rightarrow (A \approx C)$. I do not think this is correct?

I think my understanding of the mathematics is correct here, but I wonder if there is something about physics conventions that I am unaware of that makes this actually acceptable in physical calculations?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Why do you think $\approx$ wouldn't be transitive in this case?

Comment: @jacob1729 I'm not saying it necessarily isn't; I'm saying it isn't necessarily. And so, another question - one broader than the ones relating to this specific optics problem - is *given the mathematical issues I presented, what is the correct use of $\approx$ in physical calculations?*

Comment: You’re right. The reason is that it’s just a pain to write $\approx$ over and over again. So if you’re being lazy, you just write it the _first_ time you make an approximation.

Comment: This is justifiable because real calculations in physics might make 20 distinct approximations. If we didn’t do this, we would never use any equals signs at all, which would be a waste of a perfectly good symbol.

Comment: For example, even _the use of geometrical optics itself_ is an approximation, as is the assumption that the mirror is perfectly smooth, and perfectly spherical, and that the object is perfectly point like, and so on.

Comment: @knzhou Hmm, thinking about it in that sense makes me more comfortable with this. After all, all of our previous physical theories have been approximations to more accurate ones, and, without getting too far into the philosophy of this, when one thinks about those previous theories and their accuracy in making predictions about reality, they *were* essentially just approximations in the same sense that the author is making approximations in this optics example. As you were trying to convey, [...]

Comment: [...] we have quantum optics > electromagnetic optics > wave optics > ray optics, where each theory higher up in the chain has more explanatory power and provides better approximations, right?

Comment: I think it's because I'm coming from mathematics, so this hand-waviness with approximations activates alarm-bells in my head.

Comment: Maybe you're worried because this approximation doesn't have a name, unlike the rest. But it does -- it's called the paraxial approximation, and if you work in it continually, you're using the theory of paraxial optics.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks for the clarification. And what about error accumulation? See my comment to jacob1729's answer.

Comment: Yes, that can happen. In practice, we just have to remember how and when approximations break down, and work around them. For example, if you found that an angle was exactly _zero_ in the paraxial approximation, that would definitely be a case where the approximation breaks down, since you would have to go to second order in the angles to see what actually happens.

Comment: It is all very ad hoc but that's just what you need to describe reality. Maybe some very mathematical physicists refrain from any approximations -- but these people generally can't tell you how a lens works.

Comment: @knzhou Ahh, that's interesting. Why would the angle being zero cause such problems with the paraxial approximation? And why does it require us to then go to the second-order in the angles?  I thought that having a *sufficiently small angle* was the entire point of being able to make the *small angle approximation*?

Comment: Because zero would be quantitatively right (still pretty close to the right answer) but qualitatively wrong (being exactly zero is still very different from anything that's nonzero, e.g. only in the first case do you get perfectly parallel rays). It's just an example, though.

Comment: @knzhou Ahh, I see. Thanks for taking the time to explain all of this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of $\approx$ or $\sim$ in physics calculations is often vague and left undefined. However, I think it usually does have a concrete meaning in context (just one that is unstated). In your context for instance, $\approx$ means 'to first order in $\theta$'. This then *is* a transitive relation.

The main examples of specific meanings I can think of are:

a) $\sim$ being used for scalings. For instance, on dimensional grounds the period of a pendulum must be $T \sim \sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$. This is a transitive relation because if $a$ scales linearly with $b$ and $b$ with $c$ then $a$ does scale linearly with $c$. This can sometimes (as here) be replaced by the proportionality symbol $\propto$ but can also refer to asymptotic scalings in a limit.

b) Related to asymptotic scalings are low-order relations. Such as $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$ to mean 'to first order in the Taylor expansion'. These are also transitive. In a given context its possible that second order effects are important and $\approx$ then might mean ignoring third order effects.

c) 'Is of the order of magnitude of'. This is not transitive, although it might be termed approximately transitive in that if you know $a$ is the same order of magnitude as $b$ and $b$ the same order of magnitude as $c$, then at least $a$ and $c$ can only be one order apart.

---

Asked by OP in comments: "What about error propagation and accumulation in this context? What I mean is that, when making these types of approximations repeatedly, what originally may have been an acceptable, relatively minor error, could balloon into an unacceptably large error that makes the entire calculation practically useless. This is the first "practical" problem I see with this sort of interchanging of ≈ and =. How do physicists justify this?"

My point above is that this is avoided by fixing a meaning of $\approx$. Yes, if it only means 'is similar to' then errors can compound (see meaning (c)) but if it has a well defined meaning to do with scaling (a and b) then it is not just 'approximately transitive' but *actually* transitive. One must just remember the meaning of $\approx$ in the end result and interpret accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What does "to first order in $\theta$" mean?

Comment: It means that you truncate the Taylor expansion of the exact value and then truncate after the linear term. Then $\approx$ means equality in the zeroth and first order Taylor co-efficients, so it is transitive.

Comment: For a), I think you mean "$a$ does scale linearly with $c$"?

Comment: Yes, I have corrected the mistake.

Comment: I think c) should also say "and $b$ the same order of magnitude as $c$" and then "at least $a$ and $c$ can only be one order apart"?

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed that example.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What about error propagation and accumulation in this context? What I mean is that, when making these types of approximations repeatedly, what originally may have been an acceptable, relatively minor error, could balloon into an unacceptably large error that makes the entire calculation practically useless. This is the first "practical" problem I see with this sort of interchanging of $\approx$ and $=$. How do physicists justify this?